# extjs selectionmodel checkbox at initComponent

Tags: extjs

Binding checkbox selectionmodel in initComponent is not working as expected in grid component of extjs
What could be the problem in the code?  attaching fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g8r

Comment: updated fiddle link with initComponent

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind a checkbox in grid, there is a built in plugin.How ever ,if you need to attach the selModel ONLY in the initComponent.Then define grid,attach selmodel and create instance of it. .Here is the updated fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ghc

```
Ext.define('OuterGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
          store: userStore,
            storeId: 'mystore',
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            title: 'Sample Application',
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                width: 100,
                sortable: true
            }, {
                text: 'Email Address',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                width: 150,
            }, {
                text: 'Phone Number',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                    flex: 1,
            }],

    initComponent: function() {
        this.selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                    columns: [{
                        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                        text: 'Active',
                        dataIndex: 'id'
                    }],
                });

        this.callParent();   
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('OuterGrid', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However I need to attach the selModel ONLY in the initComponent.  Also is there any way to attach this plugin from any other plugin?

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle as well.Kindly check